# How to get default behaviour of ng-disabled using my own colors palette in Angular Material with AngularJS 1.x?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm using my own colors palette to set some special colors in some buttons in a section of my app. So, when I use the default palete and `md-primary` for example if I set `ng-disabled=true` the button become not clickable and the color is setted of gray. The problem is when I use myown palette, if I use `ng-disabled=true` I can't push the button but the color doesn't change and I would like that this happens.

This is an example of use:

```
<md-button
        ng-disabled="true"
        ng-click="..."
        class="md-icon-button">
    <md-icon ng-if="..." md-colors="{'color': 'specialpalette-pastelGreen'}" >
        check_circle
    </md-icon>
    <md-icon ng-if="..." md-colors="{'color': 'specialpalette-pastelRed'}">
        cancel
    </md-icon>
</md-button>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to configure in a `ng-class` like: `ng-disabled="classEnabled==false" ng-class="{'diabled-class': !classEnabled}"`, I'm not sure if there is any way to customize the disabled color.